# Using OAuth to retrieve "consumer" email from a linked Google Apps Script within a Google Apps Site

Tags: oauth, google-apps-script

While https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login is very descriptive, I cannot seem to wrap my head around how to translate into a Google Apps Script.

The ultimate goal is to have the user click a link, authorize access to their userinfo.  I will then use their email address or userId to assign the appropriate spreadsheet to other Google Apps Scripts UIs.

I am certain that some sample code would get me on my way.

Is it even possible?

Can a linked be utilized to make this happen? http://support.google.com/sites/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1224166&topic=1224152&ctx=topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble is that when you publish your script as a service, it executes under your ID. All the authorization has to be done in the script editor. So, when a third person clicks a button or link or whatever, the script runs under your user ID and all you get back is your own user id.

In short, the answer is no. Sad, but true :(

Comment: Super sad!  What about linking to the script as mentioned at the end of my post?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the OAuth code on the [Google Code site](http://code.google.com/p/oauth/). There are some great examples along with the client (and server) code in several different programming languages. Follow along with the samples on how to get the tokens needed.

Comment: Mark S. Thanks for the suggestion.  I have done a ton of research and what I am not clear on is if it is possible to get a user name or email of a "Consumer" account, one not on my domain, from withing a Google Apps Site.  Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: If a user has authorized your app to access their data (through OAuth), then you can use the meta data feed to get their information. See the [meta data](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#getting_general_information_about_a_users_account) feed information.

Comment: I brought this question up at the hangout today and Saurabh and Eric provided a reply.

Comment: Srik, what did Saurabh and Eric reply?